# RDFS, RDF missing vocabularies

Tags: rdf, ontology, rdfs

There are many examples for rdfs which use the following namespace

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
```

here is an example from w3c

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:ex="http://example.org/stuff/1.0/"
         xml:base="http://example.org/here/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:ID="snack">
    <ex:prop rdf:resource="fruit/apple"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

everything is ok, however, where rdf:Description rdf:ID are come from ?
it should be from rdf namespace

```
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
```

right?

I visited its link

http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#

but there is no rdf:Description or rdf:ID definitions.

even more, if we check for rdf:resource we can't find it, if it is from rdfs so why we did not write it like rdfs:Resource but w3c does not write it like this way, so where are these vocabularies are come frome?

is there any vocabulary used not mentioned in namespace vocabularies ?

Answer (score 1):

`rdf:ID` is defined [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/#section-Syntax-ID-xml-base) in the RDF specs.

`rdf:Description` is used for any RDF node, be it a resource or an axiom (for example, in reification).

I'm not sure if this is enough to answer your question.

Comment: But note that these are used in the rdf/xml serialization, not as part of the RDF(s) vocabulary.  E.g., you should never see "x rdf:type rdf:Description" or "x rdf:ID 67", even though other IRIs used in the same places in RDF/XML documents would produce the corresponding triples.